# Using a weaker equality test for angular select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lot's of advice tells me to do this:

```
// in js
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Foo'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}];

// in html
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
      ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
```

And that works fine.  This works fine too:

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
```

The select will be initialized to the Bar object.

But this doesn't work:

```
$scope.selectedItem = { id: 2, name: 'Bar'};
```

The select control is not initialized to the Bar object (understandably, I think). The selectedItem is equivalent to the Bar object, but not equal to it.  I have this problem in an app where parse is the back-end.  The selectedItem is a pointer from one object to another, and the items are all of the (handful) of objects in the target class.  I get these in two different queries.

Is there a way to manipulate the angular so that I still select an object, but use a custom equality test, like the object id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it will require use of an external library or some scripting of your own. You just need a lookup function which will take your key/value pair (such as you present it in your code sample) and return an item from the array.

The example below uses [`findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) in Underscore, which:

> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of
>   the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
$scope.selectedItem = _.findWhere($scope.items, {id: 2, name: 'Bar'});
```

Using .findWhere, you can also search for a subset of the key/value pairs contained in an array item, like so:

```
$scope.selectedItem = _.findWhere($scope.items, {id: 2});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LfdhUXjnk49KruVwDcr8?p=preview)

Comment: I would add that to search on just ID as the OP requested, use `_.findWhere($scope.items, {id: 2})`

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Just to be clear, it sounds like there's no way to fool angular/js into using an equivalence test, so your suggestion is to replace the equivalent object with the one in the target set that it's equivalent to.  Thanks for the help.